# chrome extension: how to insert sidebar via iframe in content?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, sidebar

I want to add a vertical side bar on the left side of the current page by injecting an iframe via chrome extension I'm building.

How can I achieve this in a way that it is consistent on any web page, like the sidebar won't end up overlapping the current page and etc. I want to make sure that the page gets pushed to the side to make room for the side bar.

I also don't want the content of the sidebar to be affected by the css styling on the current page, so I'm thinking of putting it inside an iframe.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code. We are here to help you if you're having problems with your code, not to do the job for you.

Comment: I set a big margin or padding on one side of body or html, inject a position: fixed element but not sure if this will guarantee that the sidebar will stay in place