# javascript: how to shift the entire page to the left and up?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

basically on the current page, I want to shift the entire page to the left so that I can insert a vertical sidebar using html anad also shift the page up so that I can insert a bottom bar. I want this to be consistent so that at no point will the side or bottom bars end up overlapping the contents of the current page. Basically I'm building a chrome extension and I need the side and bottom bars to show different information.

[image]

Comment: I can't imagine it would be possible to *not* overlap the content on the current page with the bottom bar. Does every web page fit on one screen? No way. There will be many pages that will require scrolling, which means the bottom bar will be covering some of the information on the page.

Comment: @MichaTodd, I see but how would it be possible to keep the side bar from overlapping with information on the page?

Comment: How about you merge this with your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224640/chrome-extension-how-to-insert-sidebar-via-iframe-in-content

Comment: Manually - edit one question and delete another.